# My Flutter App Showing "Your device isn't compatible with this version"

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app that I've just launched to the play store but in my android oreo phone, it's showing "Your device isn't compatible with this version".

In my build.gradle file

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Could someone please help me with this?

**Edit**: Also if it helps my **compileSdk version is 28**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play store reports "Your device isn't compatible with this version" but it installs via adb just fine on Nexus7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484209/play-store-reports-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-but-it-insta)

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Same here. `minSdkVersion 19` but warning is shown with my `Android 10` device.

Comment: Any update on this?