# Flutter App on play store showing error "Your device isn't compatible with this version"

Tags: flutter

Play Store keeps showing "Your device isn't compatible with this version".

I had referred to the following posts and have tried all possible ways to add/remove the permissions in Manifest file, however, I still couldn't get rid of the error in the Play Store.

[My Flutter App Showing "Your device isn't compatible with this version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028098/my-flutter-app-showing-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version)

[Your device isn't compatible with this version" but it installs via adb just fine on Nexus7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484209/play-store-reports-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-but-it-insta)

Just reaching out to you all for some solutions.

I am using Samsung S10 Android 12.

**Here is my android/app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
//    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.someApp"
//        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
//        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 33

        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

**Here is my android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.someApp">
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>

        <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

       <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Local notification Start-->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="someApp_channel" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Local notification End-->
        </activity>

       <!-- Braintree Start-->
       <activity
           android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
           android:exported="true"
           android:launchMode="singleTask">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
               <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <!-- Braintree End-->

       <!-- Image Crop Start-->
       <activity
           android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
       <!-- Image Crop End-->

       <!-- Google Pay Start-->
       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true"/>
       <!-- Google Pay End-->

       <!-- Facebook Start-->
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
           android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
       <activity 
           android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
           android:configChanges=
               "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
       android:label="someApp" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
           android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

       <activity
           android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
               <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <!-- Facebook End-->
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?